# Flutter:- How to back or redirect(Navigation) 3-4 screen previous

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-navigation

Suppose I have 6 screen "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F". First I have to navigate all the screens one by one(A=>B=C=>D=>E=>F). After that, I want to redirect the screen "F" to Screen "C" and it's working. Now my current screen is "C", So my issue is after using the back button or on back press my screen navigate to "E". but I want to navigate to screen "B".

Notes:- I don't want to use Get.off when navigating the
"D"=>"E"="F".

I'm using the Get plugin for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use popuntil

- `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);`
- `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/screen4', ModalRoute.withName('/screen1'));`

or

```
()=> Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
                      ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                    )
```

or just pop everything and then push replacement.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
// More pop
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => A()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Get.offUntil(pageB, (route) => route is pageA);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question so according to your answer We recreate the pageA.

Comment: what do you mean by recreate? it cleans the off route for the page B - cleans up everything until (route is PageA) becomes 'true'. in your case you can use ((route) => route.isFirst) instead, it will have the same effect - Get.back will point to pageA.

Comment: If update was about screen C just go with Get.offUntil(pageC, (route) => route is pageB);

Comment: I want just remove only Screen "D" and "E", not the whole screen,

Comment: This is it, offUntil deletes not the whole route, but the part of it based on (route) condition. Get.back() called from the PageC will get you to the Page B